# how to install mysql2 via Gemfile in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I started my rails project, when I went to rails console, I suffered below error,

```
$ rails c
Could not find gem 'mysql2 (>= 0.3.18, < 0.5)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

And I tried `bundle install` the result is below.

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.10' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before
bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

How can I fix such error? I doubted version conflict.if someone has already experienced such issue.please let me know Thanks.

Comment: Did u try to run `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.10' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install MySQL server and client from the packages in the Ubuntu repository. As part of the installation process, you'll set the password for the root user. This information will go into your Rails app's `database.yml` file in the future.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

Installing the libmysqlclient-dev gives you the necessary files to compile the `mysql2` gem which is what Rails will use to connect to MySQL when you setup your Rails app.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I needed

Comment: Looked at so many answers and resources. This was the only one that worked. Thanks, buddy!

Answer (score 2):

inside of your gemfile, you need

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

then try `bundle install` after adding that

Answer (score 1):

you must have mysql-server installed on you machine,

Install MySQL on you machine from this link [MySQL Installation Guide](https://itsfoss.com/install-mysql-ubuntu/)

then **bundle install** after adding **gem 'mysql2'** to you Gemfile.